# update the json after delete some data inside it

Tags: angularjs, json

I try to learn angular. currently, i already get data from JSON ( i use local JSON). I try to delete 1 of an array from JSON, its works but after I refresh the page the deleted array come back again. how to update the JSON after I delete array?

customer.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="experience in experiences">
            <td>{{experience.no}}</td>
            <td>{{experience.name}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="deleteItem(experience)" class="btn btn-danger">-</button></td>
</tr>
```

main.js

```
 resolve:{
        experiences:['$http',function($http){
        return $http.get('scripts/customer.json').then(function(response){
            return response.data
            })
        }]
    }
```

customer json

```
[
  { 
    "no":1,
    "name": "Sarah",
  },
  {
    "no":2,
    "name": "Tommy",
  }
]
```

customerCtrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('customerCtrl',['$scope','experiences',function($scope,experiences){
$scope.experiences= experiences;


$scope.deleteItem =function(experience){
    var index = $scope.experiences.indexOf(experience);
    alert("Deleting DATA: "+ index);
    $scope.experiences.splice(index,1);
};
```

}]);

Comment: You need to send deleted item to server and have server remove it from wherever it is stored

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store data in a file using javascript, which is considered as insecure and then hard to implement.

I would suggest you to use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead. Here is a service example you could use in your controller (not tested)

**localstorage service**

```
angular.module('app').service('LocalStorage', function(){

 return {
  save: function(data) {
   localStorage.setItem('data',data);
  }, 
  get: function(){
   return localStorage.getItem('data');
  }
 };
});
```

**controller**

```
// notice that I injected LocalStorage in controller
angular.module('app').controller('dataPengalamanCtrl',['$scope','experiences',function($scope,experiences, LocalStorage){
$scope.experiences= experiences;


$scope.deleteItem =function(experience){
    var index = $scope.experiences.indexOf(experience);
    alert("Deleting DATA: "+ index);
    $scope.experiences.splice(index,1);

    // First transform you're json to a string    
    var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify( $scope.experiences);

    // from there we save data to localStorage
    LocalStorage.save(stringifiedData );
};

// if you need, you can load data using :
$scope.data = LocalStorage.get();
```

Dont forget to save your json in localstorage first, for example with a file like this one :

**init.js**

```
var json = [
  { 
    "no":1,
    "name": "Sarah",
  },
  {
    "no":2,
    "name": "Tommy",
  }
];

var strData = JSON.stringify(json);
localstorage.setItem('data', strData);
```

**EDIT**
If you want to go with a remote server like myjson.com

Assuming you already saved your json on myjson.com, and url is https://api.myjson.com/bins/8hghd then :

To retrieve your json use `$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/8hghd').success(/*...*/).error(/*..*/);`

To update your json use `$http.put` with your json as data (grammar depending of your AngularJS version, see [here](http://techfunda.com/howto/573/http-put-server-request))

Have a look to the api documentation : http://myjson.com/api

Comment: i try to delete some of data on my json.  when i click delete the data is gone. but when i refresh its comeback. why the data still on my json?

Comment: Probably you didn't saved your deleted json. Each time you reload the page, you reload the previous json.